# System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type projectnetwork.Models.Branch.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriter.WriteStartElement(String name, String ns, Object o, Boolean writePrefixed, XmlSerializerNamespaces xmlns)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write7_Branch(String n, String ns, Branch o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write6_Company(String n, String ns, Company o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write7_Branch(String n, String ns, Branch o, Boolean isNullable, Boolean needType)
   at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationWriter1.Write8_Branch(Object o)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(XmlWriter xmlWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces, String encodingStyle, String id)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Serialize(TextWriter textWriter, Object o, XmlSerializerNamespaces namespaces)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.XmlReturnWriter.Write(HttpResponse response, Stream outputStream, Object returnValue)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.WriteReturns(Object[] returnValues)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.Invoke()
```

A few hours ago and so far I could not solve this problemو I am really tired and for the last chance before I became a crazy :) can I find someone who solved this problem ?
what I'm trying to do is return object of type branch which is the child include the object of his parent which is Company.

- Branch class

  ```
  public partial class Branch
  {
      public Branch()
      {
          this.Customers = new List<Customer>();
      }

          public int BranchID { get; set; }
          public int CompanyID { get; set; }
          public string BranchName { get; set; }
          public string BranchShortName { get; set; }
          public string BranchAddress { get; set; }
          public string BranchPhone { get; set; }
          public string BranchEmail { get; set; }
          public string BranchFax { get; set; }
          public Nullable<float> BranchLimit { get; set; }
          public bool RecordState { get; set; }
          public virtual Company Company { get; set; }        
      }
  ```
- Company class

  ```
  public partial class Company
  {
      public Company()
      {
          this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
      }

      public int CompanyID { get; set; }
      public string CompanyName { get; set; }
      public string CompanyShortName { get; set; }
      public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
      public string CompanyPhone { get; set; }
      public string CompanyEmail { get; set; }
      public string CompanyFax { get; set; }
      public bool RecordState { get; set; }
      public virtual List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
  }
  ```
- NewDBContext class

  ```
  using System.Data.Entity;
  using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
  using projectnetwork.Models.Mapping;

  namespace projectnetwork.Models
  {
  public partial class NewDBContext : DbContext
  {
      static NewDBContext()
      {
          Database.SetInitializer<NewDBContext>(null);
      }

      public NewDBContext()
          : base("Name=NewDBContext")
      {
          this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled   = false;
          this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
      }

      public DbSet<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
      public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }

      protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
      {
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new BranchMap());
          modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new CompanyMap());          
      }
  }
  }
  ```
- Call Method

  ```
      [WebMethod]
      public Branch getAllCustomers()
      {
          Branch  br = null;

          using (var db = new NewDBContext())
          {
              br = db.Branches
                  .Where(d => d.CompanyID == 1)
                  .Include(c => c.Company)
                  .FirstOrDefault<Branch>();                  


              return br;

          }
  ```

sorry for my bad English

Comment: you have defined public virtual Company Company { get; set; }     in side Branches and public virtual List<Branch> Branches { get; set; } inside Company.

Comment: @MihaiHantea  var collection = br.Select(b => new { //copy your properties to the new object }); !!!! doesn't work

Comment: @ray not me who defined this I used entity frame work tool to generate these classes

Comment: @MihaiHantea I disabled it look at NewDBContext class

Comment: @GertArnold look at NewDBContext clas I turned it off

Comment: conceptually, the Branch should hold only the companyID. With that companyID you should be able to get the company details.

Comment: Are your classed marked with `DataContract` attribute?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding a `JsonIgnore` attribute on your class to stop it being rendered, if you are using Newtonsoft.Json

```
public partial class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Branches = new List<Branch>();
    }

    ....

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual List<Branch> Branches { get; set; }
```

}

Comment: I think he uses `Microsoft.Xml.Serialization`, which is mentioned in a stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to set [IsReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.isreference%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) proeprty of DataContract attribute to true. Some extra details are [here](http://zamd.net/2008/05/20/datacontract-serializer-and-isreference-property/).

```
[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
```