# InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type Synapse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to save training data

```
public void saveNetwork()
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer (OutputLayer.GetType());
    var stream = new FileStream ("Assets/Dataset.xml", FileMode.CreateNew);
    serializer.Serialize (stream, OutputLayer);
    stream.Close ();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System.InvalidOperationException: A circular reference was detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22294161/system-invalidoperationexception-a-circular-reference-was-detected)

Comment: Also a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082294/error-while-xml-serializing-an-object) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815182/circular-reference-when-using-xml-serialization). Easily found with Google. And your code above isn't an [mcve]. I can take that and it will work with my object because my object doesn't have circular references and yours does.

Comment: What John means is, you didn't supply the object being serialized, so we can't reproduce your issue.